# C++ time.h difftime

Tags: c++, time, truncate, floor

I am in trouble with interpreting `difftime` quantity in a log I have produced:

I measure duration for some method call, and I log it, with this syntax:

```
time_t end, start ;

time(&start);

obj->sqp_func(this);

time(&end);

t_time = difftime(end, start) ;

sqp << "time " << endl ;
sqp << (double) end <<  endl ;
sqp << (double) start << endl ; 
sqp << (double) t_time << endl ;
```

where `sqp`is of `ofstream` type.

I get, where `t_time` (with type `double`) should be printed, the value 210.

Are those 210 seconds? Is it truncated, or floored?

How can I get result in seconds up to 2 floating points for instance?

Comment: Better yet, use `std::chrono`.

Comment: @MarkGarcia some C++11 i guess? who can compile C++11 BTW (which version of VS ?) ?

Comment: VS2010 has some support for c++11 (chrono is supported). VS2012 has full-blown support for c++11.

Comment: @MarkGarcia In fact VS2010 does **not** have `std::chrono`. *"VS2012 has full-blown support for c++11"* - well, for the library to be clear. Though even that is incomplete, missing at least C++11 mathematical functions and functions for controlling the floating point environment.

Comment: @MarkGarcia do you know how to set precision with difftime to print in ostream ? i am using `outpt << std::fixed << std::setprecision(10) << (double) time  << endl ;` and it is printing... 10 zeros after floating point, not improving precision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`difftime` returns **difference in seconds** of type **double** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/difftime/
 - see this for detailed explanations

Comment: thanks, how would you show in ofstream file two digits floating point precision then?

Comment: As difftime calculates difference of two values of type time_t(is integer value) you can`t get precision higher than one second.   As difftime returns value of type double you can put it`s value in file in 2 digital point percision format using syntax like this:   fprintf (pFile,"%.2lf", dif);   or using object oriented i/o: cout.precision(2);
cout << dif << endl;

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a timer with a higher resolution (if you can not use C++11).  - [Like this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/clock_gettime). For your case `clockid_t - CLOCK_MONOTONIC`.